# Categorizing the survey respondents from the set of questionnaire

Tags: survey

I want to evaluate the result from the set of questionnaires. 14-item scales will be used and this will include three subscales let's say A, B, and C.

All items will be scored on a 7-point frequency rating scale ranging from `0 (never) to 6(always)`.

The survey will be conducted from the 109 respondents.

With those 14-item scales in total, I want to categorize the student in three classes.

> I wanted to classify the result as High, Medium, and Low.

I know the basic statistics and tools for conducting statistical analysis.

But, I couldn't generate any idea on how to do this type of analysis. Any help or pointing towards the appropriate analysis methods will be appreciated?

Comment: please suggest some appropriate tags for this question.

Comment: Consider the metric NPS score.